# Why permission error when using T-SQL but not when using SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-managed-instance, sql-server-2022

When trying to run the following to create a `Server Role`, I get permission error shown below. But I can successfully create the same role using `SSMS`. Question: Why?

```
CREATE SERVER ROLE TestRole AUTHORIZATION [dbo];
```

> Error: Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1
> Cannot find the server principal 'dbo', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server role is a server level securable. Because of that it is owned by a login, not a user. Dbo is a user. Either remove the authorization clause or specify a relevant login as the owner.